# alfresco passing a username to a link doclibaction

Tags: alfresco

I need to pass the username to a link in a doclibaction.  I am using share alfresco 4.2.
The following section is from my share-config-custom.xml file.

```
<action id="document-edit-xmlapp" type="link" label="actions.document.document-edit-xmlapp">
   <param name="href">http://alfresco.eb.com/oxygen-sdk-sample-webapp/app/oxygen.html?url=webdav-http://alfresco.eb.com/alfresco{webdavUrl}&amp;showSave=true&amp;author={?this is what I need?}</param>       
   <permissions> 
     <permission allow="true">Write</permission>
   </permissions>
   <evaluator>evaluator.doclib.action.checkInXMLEdit</evaluator>
</action>
```

I need to pass the username to the author query parameter. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks 
Mark

Comment: I'm not sure what parameters are available in actions, but I would try to use `{node.properties.author}` or `{node.properties.creator}`

Comment: Mark, does streetturtle answer / comment helped you ?

Comment: Thanks, the {node.properties.creator} led me in the right direction. I wound up using {node.properties.modifier.userName}.

Answer (score 0):

My final section of code that worked was

```
<action id="document-edit-xmlapp" type="link" label="actions.document.document-edit-xmlapp">
   <param name="href">http://alfresco.eb.com/oxygen-sdk-sample-webapp/app/oxygen.html?url=webdav-http://alfresco.eb.com/alfresco{webdavUrl}&amp;showSave=true&amp;author={node.properties.modifier.userName}</param>       
   <permissions> 
     <permission allow="true">Write</permission>
   </permissions>
   <evaluator>evaluator.doclib.action.checkInXMLEdit</evaluator>
</action>
```